# Why get post meta single parameter isn't working if key is empty

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I wanted to get all the post meta using this code:

```
$metas = get_post_meta( $post_id, '', true );
```

The code above will output an array that looks something like:

```
array(
    'sample_key1' => array(
        [0] => 'value1'
    ),
    'sample_key2' => array(
        [0] => 'value2'
    ),
    'sample_key3' => array(
        [0] => 'value3'
    )
)
```

Rather than

```
array(
    'sample_key1' => 'value1',
    'sample_key2' => 'value2',
    'sample_key3' => 'value3'
)
```

hence the $single param is true.

It will work when you put a specific key like:

```
$meta1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sample_meta1' );
```

will output something like:

```
array(
    [0] => 'value1'
)
```

and when the $single param is true:

```
$meta1 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'sample_meta1', true );
```

will output something like:

```
'value1'
```

I would appreciate any answer I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [get_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/#source) function using `get_metadata()` function. And according to documentation [get_metadata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/#parameters) the 3rd bool parameter only work if the meta_key exists.

> If true, return only the first value of the specified meta_key. This parameter has no effect if meta_key is not specified.

Hope this helped you to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [get_post_custom()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom) method as well.
It returns a multidimensional array with all custom fields of a particular post or page

Comment: Well, the real issue on my posts is that why get_post_meta's $single param isn't working when meta key is empty.